# Invalid index in Scilab fsolve, but can't find anything

Tags: matlab, solver, scilab

I am trying to solve a non linear equation, however, I ge tan error in line 2 and the  last line. It says invalid index, in scilab.

````
    w=Ms*(A*(Tss-x)+B*0.5*(Tss*Tss-x*x)+C*0.3333*(Tss^3-x^3)+D*0.25(Tss^4-x^4)-E/(Tss-x))-Mf*Cpsoln*(Tb-Tin)-Ms*latent;
endfunction

[two]=fsolve([150],[enbal]);```
````

Comment: Please give the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `*` between 0.25 and the parenthesis here : `0.25(Tss`. And on the first line remove the brackets around `enbal`.